# Помогите перевести с Pascal на C++

Tags: c++, pascal

Надо перевести уже полностью готовый код с паскаля на С++, пыталась сама, но почему то не выходит. =(

*программа на Паскале:*

```
var
  arrMatrix: array of array of Integer;
  i: Integer;

procedure Print;
var
  i, j, arrCount: Integer;
begin
  arrCount := Length(arrMatrix);
  for i := 0 to arrCount - 1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to arrCount - 1 do
      Write(arrMatrix[i, j]:5);
    Writeln;
  end;
end;

procedure perestanovka(var oldI: Integer; var oldJ: Integer; i, j: Integer);
var
  tmp: Integer;
begin
  if arrMatrix[oldI, oldJ] > arrMatrix[i, j] then
  begin
    tmp := arrMatrix[oldI, oldJ];
    arrMatrix[oldI, oldJ] := arrMatrix[i, j];
    arrMatrix[i, j] := tmp;
  end;
  oldI := i;
  oldJ := j;
end;

procedure zmeika;
var
  i, j, oldI, oldJ: integer;
  arrCount: Integer;
begin
  arrCount := Length(arrMatrix) - 1;
  i := arrCount;
  j := 0;
  oldI := i;
  oldJ := j;
  repeat
    if j < arrCount then
    begin
      Inc(j);
      perestanovka(oldI, oldJ, i, j);
    end
    else
    begin
      Dec(i);
      perestanovka(oldI, oldJ, i, j);
    end;

    while (i > 0) and (j > 0) do
    begin
      Dec(j);
      Dec(i);
      perestanovka(oldI, oldJ, i, j);
    end;

    if i > 0 then
    begin
      Dec(i);
      perestanovka(oldI, oldJ, i, j);
    end
    else
    if j < arrCount then
    begin
      inc(j);
      perestanovka(oldI, oldJ, i, j);
    end;

    while (i < arrCount) and (j < arrCount) do
    begin
      Inc(i);
      Inc(j);
      perestanovka(oldI, oldJ, i, j);
    end;
  until (i = 0) and (j = arrCount);
end;

procedure RandMatr;
var
  arrCount: Integer;
  i, j: integer;
begin
  Randomize;

  Writeln('Введите размер матрицы');
  Readln(arrCount);
  SetLength(arrMatrix, arrCount);

  for i := 0 to arrCount - 1 do
  begin
    SetLength(arrMatrix[i], arrCount);
    for j := 0 to arrCount - 1 do
      arrMatrix[i, j] := Random(898) + 101;
  end;
end;

begin
  RandMatr;
  Writeln;
  Print;
  Writeln;
  for i := 1 to Length(arrMatrix) * Length(arrMatrix) - 1 do
    zmeika;
  Print;

  Readln;
end.
```

`

`*На С ( не работает)*

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int i,arrCount;

int** arrMatrix = new int* [arrCount];

void Print ()
{

    int arrCount=arrCount*arrCount;

    for(int i=0;i < (arrCount - 1); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<(arrCount-1);j++)
        {

        cout.width(3);
        cout<< arrMatrix[i][j];
        cout<<"\n";
        } 
    }
}
int perestanovka(int oldI, int oldJ, int i, int j)
{
    if(arrMatrix[oldI][oldJ]>arrMatrix[i][j])
    {
        int tmp=arrMatrix[oldI][oldJ];
        arrMatrix[oldI][oldJ]=arrMatrix[i][j];
        arrMatrix[i][j]=tmp;
    }
    oldI=i;
    oldJ=j;
    return (oldI);
    return (oldJ);
}

void zmeika()
{
    i=arrCount=arrCount*arrCount- 1;

    int j=0;
    int oldI=i;
    int oldJ=j;

    do
    {
        if (j<arrCount)
        {
            ++j;
            perestanovka(oldI,oldJ,i,j);

        }
        else
        {
            --i;
            perestanovka(oldI,oldJ,i,j);
        }

        while ((i>0) && (j>0))
        {
            --j;
            --i;
            perestanovka(oldI,oldJ,i,j);
        }
        if(i>0)
        {
            --i;
            perestanovka(oldI,oldJ,i,j);
        }
        else
        {
            if (j<arrCount)
            {
                ++j;
                perestanovka(oldI,oldJ,i,j);
            }
        }
        while((i<arrCount) && (j<arrCount))
        {
            ++i;
            ++j;
            perestanovka(oldI,oldJ,i,j);
        }
    }
    while((i==0) && (j==arrCount));

}

void RandMatr()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout<<"Введите размер матрицы "<<"\n";
    cin>> arrCount;
    srand (time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<(arrCount-1);i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<(arrCount-1);j++)
        {
            arrMatrix[i][j]=rand();
        }
    }
}


int main ()
{


 int** arrMatrix = new int* [arrCount];
 for( i = 0; i< arrCount; i++)
 {
 arrMatrix[i] = new int [arrCount];
 }



     RandMatr();
     Print();
     for(i = 1;i<(arrCount*arrCount) *(arrCount*arrCount) - 1;i++) 
     zmeika();
     Print();

     for(int i = 0; i < arrCount; i++)
     {
        delete [] arrMatrix[i];
     }
     delete [] arrMatrix;

     getch();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы хотя бы укажите, где компилятор ругается.  
И напишите, что делает программа.  
`array of array of Integer;` - это что?  
Вы не объявили переменную j в функции Print, и вообще она какая-та странная.

Comment: Если вам это поможет, могу отправить все задание. 
А так если не ошибаюсь это момент создания динамического массива.
Компилятору  не нравится строка 

arrMatrix[i][j]=rand();

Comment: Программа сначала выводит на экран рандомно заполненную матрицу(размер вводится с клавиатуры) , потом сортирует ее змейкой( она идет по диагоналям) по возрастанию, начиная с нижнего левого угла .

Comment: Очевидно, что return (oldJ); в функции perestanovka не выполняется.  
Можно просто объявить все переменные, как переменные класса. Тогда будет легче переписать код  с Паскаля.

Comment: Насчет промежутка генерации рандома: уже пыталась, безнадежно. Только промежуток брала от 100 до 999 

Я не совсем понимаю, как это: объявить переменные как переменные класса (  Я вообще в С не очень разбираюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас и не C, и не C++, а смесь французского с нижегородским. Так делать никогда не надо, либо C (что в вашем случае будет намного сложней), либо C++ и никакого "ручного" распределения памяти для матриц.

Во-вторых, программа, очевидно, трапается в этом месте:

```
for(int i=0;i<(arrCount-1);i++)
{
  for (int j=0;j<(arrCount-1);j++)
  {
    arrMatrix[i][j]=rand(); // вот здесь
  }
}
```

Потому что вы сначала распределяете память под arrMatrix (в main()), и только потом инициализируете размер матрицы, то есть arrCount. До вызова RandMatr значение arrCount не определено, и какой бардак творится у вас с памятью, кто куда пишет - непредсказуемо. Скорее всего, значение arrCount инициализировано нулём, что вносит ещё больше эротики в этот фрагмент:

```
int** arrMatrix = new int* [arrCount];
for( i = 0; i< arrCount; i++)
{
  arrMatrix[i] = new int [arrCount];
}
```

Ну и в-третьих, если бы вы запустили программу под отладчиком, то место падения было бы определено сразу же, и минута-полторы пошаговой отладки с просмотром переменных всё бы прояснили. Всяко надёжней, чем гадать на кофейной гуще, и намного быстрей, чем ждать пока это сделает кто-то другой...